# Overloading a function based on the ability to call the stream output operator on its arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have a generic function that takes two arguments, compares them, and prints a message if they're not equal. Right now, I just have this relatively dumb function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
static void AreEqual(const T& expected,
                     const T& actual,
                     const std::string& message = "") {
    if (!(actual == expected)) {
        std::cout << message;
    }
}
```

This has worked adequately for many years. It's most often called with primitives, but also gets used to compare larger user-defined structs/classes.

I would like to extend the function by providing an overload that prints the expected and actual values when they don't match, but without breaking the function for classes that define `operator==` but don't define `operator<<`. My idea is to create an overload that uses SFINAE to disable the overload if `operator<<` is missing. I've come up with this so far:

```cpp
template <
    typename T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<decltype(std::cout << *((T*)nullptr)), decltype(std::cout)>>>
static void AreEqual(const T& expected,
                     const T& actual,
                     const std::string& message = "") {
    if (!(actual == expected)) {
        std::cout << "Expected " << expected << ", got " << actual << ". " << message;
    }
}
```

This compiles, but it doesn't get selected for `T` of `int` or `std::string` and I'm not sure why. My first suspicion is that my arguments to `is_same_v` are malformed somehow, but I have no idea how or how to figure out how to fix it if that's the case.

Question 1: Is all of this even necessary? Could I achieve the same result without template meta programming (preferably while sticking with C++11)

Question 2: If this is the best way forward, how to I effectively debug my templates?

Comment: `*((T*)nullptr)` i think you are looking for [std::declval<T>()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

Comment: `decltype(std::cout << std::declval<T>()))` would be `std::ostream&`, whereas `decltype(std::cout)` is `std::ostream`.

Comment: usually I end up needing `T&` in `std::declval<T&>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
struct overload_low_priority {};
struct overload_high_priority : overload_low_priority {};


template <typename T>
static auto AreEqualImpl(const T& expected,
                         const T& actual,
                         const std::string& message,
                         overload_high_priority)
-> decltype(std::cout << expected, void()) // SFINAE
{
    if (!(actual == expected)) {
        std::cout << "Expected " << expected << ", got " << actual << ". " << message;
    }
}

template <typename T>
static void AreEqualImpl(const T& expected,
                         const T& actual,
                         const std::string& message,
                         overload_low_priority) // Fallback
{
    if (!(actual == expected)) {
        std::cout << message;
    }
}

template <typename T>
static void AreEqual(const T& expected,
                     const T& actual,
                     const std::string& message = "")
{
    AreEqualImpl(expected, actual, message, overload_high_priority{});
}
```

Comment: This actually solves the problem quite well. I hadn't encountered this method of applying SFINAE to return types before. It even appears to work for C++11, which is and added bonus for me.

Answer (score 0):

I propose something different.

Instead of `std::cout` (or not) the values `expected` and `actual`, you could ever print the value returned by a function called from the values. So you could differentiate (overloading) the behavior of the called function.

I mean... suppose you write two version of the function `maybePrint()`.

The first one is a template pass-through function, SFINAE enabled only if the template type is printable

```
template <typename T>
auto maybePrint (T const & t) -> decltype( std::cout << t, t )
 { return t; }
```

The second one, called when the first isn't available (so when the argument is unprintable), return an informative string (well... maybe choose a better string) [EDIT: modified following a report from Jarod42]

```
template <typename ... Ts>
std::string maybePrint (Ts const & ...)
 { return "[maybe not]"; }
```

So your `AreEqual()` become

```
template <typename T>
static void AreEqual(const T& expected,
                     const T& actual,
                     const std::string& message = "")
 {
   if ( ! (actual == expected) )
      std::cout << "Expected " << maybePrint(expected) << ", got "
         << maybePrint(actual) << ". " << message;
 }
```

I suggest this solution also because, tomorrow or in a far distant future, you could be tempted to modify the `AreEqual()` to differentiate the template types.

This because the following call

```
AreEqual(1, 2l, "abc\n");
```

gives a compilation error because the compiler can't choose between `T = int` (`1` is `int`) and `T = long` (`2l` is `long`).

If you rewrite `AreEqual()` receiving two arguments of (potentially) two different types

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
static void AreEqual (T1 const & expected,
                      T2 const & actual,
                      std::string const & message = "")
 {
   if ( ! (actual == expected) )
      std::cout << "Expected " << maybePrint(expected) << ", got "
         << maybePrint(actual) << ". " << message;
 }
```

the preceding call compile because `T1` is deduced `int` and `T2` is deduced `long`.

If you enable one version or the other of `AreEqual()` according `T1` and `T2` you have (potentially) four cases (`T1` and `T2` printable; `T1` printable, `T2` not; `T2` printable, `T1` not; both `T1` and `T2` not printable) so four version of `AreEqual()`.

Working through `maybePrint()` you maintain a single `AreEqual()`.

Comment: I think it is UB to pass object in ellipsis.

Comment: @Jarod42 - I didn't know at all but, with a rapid search, I see other that say that is UB for not-POD types. Have you a standard reference? Anyway, modified the answer using a variadic template function instead. Thanks.

Comment: Now, it would be ambiguous (and you require and do extra copy).

Comment: @Jarod42 - the extra copy goes away with a `const &` (if I'm not wrong) but why ambigous? Isn't a better match the one-template version?

Comment: After check, not ambiguous, sorry.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Never mind; C++ has become so complex that, very often, I don't know if make sense what I'm writing.